# jquery data coming with page source

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is a basic javascript function. What this does is takes post id goes to the particular url performs some operations and returns result as true / false. But this is actually not happening. It is returning the whole page source in alert(data). I want to see only the returned true/false result. Please help

```
function cool_add(post_id)
{   
$.post('cool_main.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data) {

    alert(data);

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    // Contains all the cool functions 
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    } 

    require('connect.php'); 
?> 

<?php 
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id']; 
    if ($post_id == 1)
    { 
        return true; 
    }
    else { 
        return false; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: What true/false result? Where is it in the response? Why not just send a simple string/json value?

Comment: You should change the code of cool_main.php to return only a boolean instead of the whole page.

Comment: Can you add the contents of `cool_main.php`?

Comment: You need to use JSON format to get this working right. Try `return json_encode(array("success" => true/false));` and then in the `$.post()` function `alert(data.success)` :)

Comment: @tftd This wouldn't work, as `$.post()` does not objectify the returned JSON by default.

Answer (score 1):

`return true` in PHP is used to return values from functions. A jQuery AJAX-call assigns the `data` variable with whatever the PHP-file prints out.

Here's a simple way to transfer boolean via JSON:

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>true));
```

jQuery:

```
$.post('cool_main.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data){
    alert(data.result); //true
}, 'json');
```

**Another method:**

```
echo 'true';
```

jQuery:

```
$.post('cool_main.php', {post_id:post_id}, function(data){
    alert(data); //"true"
});
```

Comment: The variable `data` is what your PHP-file prints out. `return true` does not print anything. Replace it with e.g. `echo 'true/false';` and try it.

Comment: Both suggestions are correct. Usually it's better if you use JSON format to receive AJAX responses - it preserves data types.

Answer (score 0):

The data that is returned from an AJAX call is determined by the URL you are calling, in this case `cool_main.php`. Amending this javascript will not help, you need to amend your PHP file to return just a boolean result.

Comment: I didnt understand this. The javascript is calling cool_main.php. The php returns just true/false after performing some operations. But when i see what is returned using javascript i.e alert(data) i see the page source along with the result in alert. I dont want the source. It is coming like <html><body><body><html>true. I dont know what where the tags are coming. In my php file on php code is there no html.

Comment: Could you edit your question above to include the source of you PHP page, please.

Comment: My php:
<?php 
// Contains all the cool functions 
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
require('connect.php'); 
?>
<?php
$post_id=$_POST['post_id'];
if($post_id==1){
return true;
}else
{
return false;
}
i need the connect.php so please ignore that. This should only give true/false in js alert but i m getting page source along with that.

Comment: I m sorry i couldnt edit the question some errors were coming

Answer (score 0):

data will contain whatever cool_main.php is returning.

My guess is that your cool_main.php is not recognizing the post vars you are sending it.

Comment: I didnt understand this. The javascript is calling cool_main.php. The php returns just true/false after performing some operations. But when i see what is returned using javascript i.e alert(data) i see the page source along with the result in alert. I dont want the source. It is coming like <html><body><body><html>true. I dont know what where the tags are coming. In my php file on php code is there no html.

Answer (score 0):

There could be few possible reasons. The issue is not with your javascript code but with server side scripting logic in `cool_main.php`.

In your PHP page you have to identify ajax requests and response only 'true/false' according to your example. Make sure nothing will be sent to the browser other than that data.

If you are using a MVC framework like Zend, you may require to disable layouts, views in such cases.